# Every second request fails to route within Docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I'm not too sure how to investigate this issue, essentially I deployed a set of services to a swarm using a command like:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-swarm.yml config | docker stack deploy -c testing1`.

This is a single node cluster (on a single machine).

Why is every second request failing to route?

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8091
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C^C^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

And on a second attempt:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8091
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

Within the `docker-compose-swarm.yml` I have a network used and defined as:

```
networks:
  navigator-imagegallery-network:
    driver: overlay
```

---

**Additional debug information:**

tcpdump on first request (successful):

```
sudo tcpdump  -v -i any tcp port 8091
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
16:13:17.573503 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1247, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.60974 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0x078a), seq 831371862, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928057139 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:17.573516 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1247, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.60974 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0x078a), seq 831371862, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928057139 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:17.573603 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    172.30.0.2.jamlink > archamd.60974: Flags [S.], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0x44e0), seq 623836494, ack 831371863, win 27960, options [mss 1410,sackOK,TS val 1733128342 ecr 2928057139,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:17.573603 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    172.30.0.2.jamlink > localhost.localdomain.60974: Flags [S.], cksum 0x2b50 (incorrect -> 0x71fe), seq 623836494, ack 831371863, win 27960, options [mss 1410,sackOK,TS val 1733128342 ecr 2928057139,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:13:17.573621 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1248, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    archamd.60974 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [.], cksum 0x5866 (incorrect -> 0xdf5c), ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928057139 ecr 1733128342], length 0
16:13:17.573623 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1248, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    archamd.60974 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [.], cksum 0x5866 (incorrect -> 0xdf5c), ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928057139 ecr 1733128342], length 0
16:13:17.573711 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 1249, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 138)
    archamd.60974 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [P.], cksum 0x58bc (incorrect -> 0xe5f0), seq 1:87, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 2928057139 ecr 1733128342], length 86
```

tcpdump on second request (failure):

```
sudo tcpdump  -v -i any tcp port 8091
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
16:14:33.896311 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17252, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.32944 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0xeed3), seq 2620107720, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928133462 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:14:33.896324 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17252, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.32944 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0xeed3), seq 2620107720, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928133462 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:14:34.939687 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17253, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.32944 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0xeac0), seq 2620107720, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928134505 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:14:34.939702 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17253, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.32944 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0xeac0), seq 2620107720, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928134505 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:14:36.987820 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17254, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.32944 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0xe2bf), seq 2620107720, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928136554 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:14:36.987829 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 17254, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    archamd.32944 > 172.30.0.2.jamlink: Flags [S], cksum 0x586e (incorrect -> 0xe2bf), seq 2620107720, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 2928136554 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Output of `docker version`:

```
Client:
 Version:   18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.10
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 01:47:41 2018
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10
  Git commit:   0520e24302
  Built:    Fri Mar 23 01:48:12 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

**docker-compose-swarm.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  proxy-nginx:
    container_name: 'proxy-nginx'
    image: stuartshay/navigator-identity-proxy:development
    depends_on:
      - api-imagegallery
      - api-navigator-identity
    ports:
      - "8101:8101"
      - "8091:8091"
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - nginx-log-volume:/var/log/nginx/ 
    networks:
      - navigator-imagegallery-network

  api-imagegallery:
    container_name: 'gcapi-imagegallery'
    image: stuartshay/imagegallery-api:2.0-local
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Docker
      DB_SERVER: database
      SA_PASSWORD: ${SA_PASSWORD}
      openIdConnectConfiguration:authority : ${AUTHORITY}
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - www-root-volume:/publish/wwwroot  
    networks:
      - navigator-imagegallery-network

  api-navigator-identity:
    container_name: 'gcapi-navigator-identity'
    image: stuartshay/navigator-identity-api:1.1.5-local   
    environment:
       ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Docker
       DB_SERVER: database
       SA_PASSWORD: ${SA_PASSWORD}
       AuthClients:ImageGalleryApi : ${IMAGE_GALLERY_API}
       AuthClients:ImageGalleryClient : ${IMAGE_GALLERY_CLIENT}
    networks:
      - navigator-imagegallery-network

  config-identityserverdb:
    container_name: 'gcconfig-identityserverdb'
    image: stuartshay/navigator-identity-configuration:2.1-build
    environment:
       ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Staging
       DB_SERVER: database
       SA_PASSWORD: ${SA_PASSWORD}
    command: "/wait_for_it.sh -h database -p 1433 -t 0 -- dotnet NavigatorIdentity.Configuration.IdentityServerDataDB.dll"
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - navigator-imagegallery-network

  redis:
    container_name: 'gcredis'
    image: stuartshay/navigator-identity-redis:development
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli","ping"]
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis-data-volume:/var/lib/redis
    restart: always
    networks:
      - navigator-imagegallery-network

  database:
    container_name: 'gcdatabase'
    hostname: database
    image: "stuartshay/navigator-identity-sqlserver:2017-CU5"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: ${SA_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: sqlcmd -S database -U SA -P ${SA_PASSWORD} -Q 'select 1'  
    volumes:
      - sql-backup-volume:/backup
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    depends_on:
      - mail  
    networks:
    - navigator-imagegallery-network

  mail:
    container_name: 'gcmail'
    hostname: mail
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - navigator-imagegallery-network

volumes:
  nginx-log-volume:
  sql-data-volume:
  sql-backup-volume:
  www-root-volume:
  redis-data-volume:

networks:
  navigator-imagegallery-network:
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: can you post your compose file? did you publish your services to those ports on host? what docker version? what host OS?

Comment: Seems to be a bug : https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2855

Comment: That's the repo for the legacy swarm. I added a comment to it.